# ControlTemplate MahApps.Metro VisualStateManager State Transition Problems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, mahapps.metro

I am experimenting with the radio button control template from MahApps.Metro. 
My App.xaml looks the same as in http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html

I copied the control template via VS context menu, my window looks like this:

```xaml
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahAppsRadioButtonControlTemplateWrapTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RBStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource LabelTextBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource ContentFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource ContentFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                     <!-- Uncomment the line below to break the radio button -->
                     <!-- <Grid> -->
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftCol" Width="18"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightCol" Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="hover"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pressed"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="disabled"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Checked1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="focused"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_CHECKBOX">
                                <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource TransparentWhiteBrush}" Margin="-6,0"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="normal" Fill="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" Height="18" Opacity="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource CheckBoxBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="18"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="hover" Fill="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" Height="18" Opacity="0" Stroke="{DynamicResource CheckBoxMouseOverBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="18"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="pressed" Fill="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" Height="18" Opacity="0" Stroke="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="18"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="focused" Fill="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" Height="18" Opacity="0" Stroke="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="18"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="Checked1" Fill="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}" Height="10" Opacity="0" Width="10"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="disabled" Fill="{DynamicResource SemiTransparentWhiteBrush}" Height="18" Opacity="0" StrokeThickness="1" Width="18"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                     <!-- Uncomment the line below to break the radio button -->
                     <!-- </Grid> -->
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="controls:ControlsHelper.ContentDirection" Value="RightToLeft">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,6,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="LeftCol" Value="*"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="RightCol" Value="18"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="PART_CHECKBOX" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource RBStyle}">Foo</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton>Bar</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton>Baz</RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

If I wrap the outer Grid of the control template within another Grid control, the radio button works normally but the checked mark never shows.

Can someone explain me what's going on?

Comment: So it works as expected EXCEPT that the `Checked1` Ellipse doesn't display? Are the other visuals present for the other states etc? This is a nifty mystery.

Comment: Yes, I checked the Click and Checked events, and monitored the IsChecked property too. 
The external ellipse is displayed, but the filled circle inside it is not.

Comment: The control looks the same for IsEnabled = True and IsEnabled = False

Comment: For ****'s and giggles, what happens if you move your VSM to the *new outer parent Grid? Any change? Sorry I dont have a proj with mahapps or anything to test on at the moment

Comment: It worked. I don't know why but it did, going to investigate :-O
[EDIT]
It's documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330302(v=vs.110).aspx#defining_the_visual_structure_and_visual_behavior_of_a_control_in_a_controltemplate) See the little note at the end of the section.

Comment: Ya actually I would expect that too, it's a template thing. I'm on my way out the door but will get back on and explain later, it's an interesting quirk. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like I was saying, it's an interesting quirk whereby the element (in this case your transition targets) that's in a [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will only inherit from the outer-most parent [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Which, is one of those things that can really confuse ya when you're sitting there thinking "wtf? all I did was add a damn `Grid` around it..." Right?

For more info checkout this doc article about [Changing the Visual Structure of a Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#changing_the_visual_structure_of_a_control) and you can get the full explanation.

Anyway, glad it helped!